# Applying Stokes Theorem Without Vector Field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

**Q:** Evaluate $\oint_S 4x dx + 9y dy + 3(x^2 +y^2) dz$ where $S$ is the boundary of the surface $z=4-x^2-y^2$ where $x,y,z \ge 0$, oriented counterclockwise as viewed from above.

I am a bit confused with how to do this question since I'm not given a vector field. Do I not apply Stoke's theorem? Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** I now know that I can express this as a vector field **F** $=4x$**i** $+9y$**j** $+3(x^2+y^2)$**k**. Using the cross product, I have found curl**F**$=6y$**i** $-6x$**j**, and want to evaluate $\oint_S 4x dx + 9y dy + 3(x^2 +y^2) dz$ using Stokes' theorem ($\iint_S$ curl**F** $\cdot$ **n** $dA$). However, I am unsure how to calculate **n**, the unit normal of $S$ which in this case would be the surface $z=4-x^2-y^2$ restricted to $x,y,z \ge 0$. Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: If $\mathbf{F} = P\mathbf{i} + Q\mathbf{j} + R\mathbf{k}$ is a vector field, then $\int_C P\,dx+Q\,dy+R\,dz$ is another traditional way to write the line integral $\int_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$ of $\mathbf{F}$ over a curve $C$. Can you now see how to extract the relevant vector field $\mathbf{F}$ from the line integral you were given?

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Ah so I can think of this as the vector $F=4xi+9yj+3(x^2 +y^2)k$?

Comment: That's exactly right—you can now take the curl of this vector field $\mathbf{F}$ and apply Stokes’s theorem. As for finding the unit normal $\mathbf{n}$, note that $z=4-x^2-y^2$ is the equation of the graph of the function $f(x,y) = 4-x^2-y^2$. Does this give you an idea for how to parameterize your surface?

Comment: I was thinking of using cylindrical coordinates $(r, \theta)$ where $0 \le r \le 2$. Since we're interested in the paraboloid in the octant where $x,y,z \ge 0$, will these affect the upper bound of $\theta$? Because for a regular unrestricted paraboloid I would have $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$.

Comment: Absolutely. $0 \leq r \leq 2$ takes care of the condition $z \geq 0$, but now you need to account for $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$, which you can make sense of by thinking about polar coordinates in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: $\cos \theta \ge 0$ if $0 \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\sin \theta \ge 0$ if $0 \le \theta \le \pi$, so it makes sense to me to take the lesser of the two and have $0 \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$. Does this account for it properly?

Comment: Indeed it does. You can also make sense of this geometrically. If you fix the polar coordinate $r > 0$ and move counterclockwise along the resulting circle, then having no restriction on $x$ or $y$ means that you get the whole circle, hence $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$. If you restrict to $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$, then you're getting the quarter circle in the first quadrant, hence $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$.

Comment: Okay so I have my parametrisation of $S$, and I have converted my equation for the curl of $F$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$, however I am unsure how to use this for **n**. I know a cross product is involved, but that's about it.

Comment: If $\mathbf{\Psi} : (0,2) \times [0,\pi/2] \to \Sigma$ is the parameterization of your surface $\Sigma$ in terms of $(r,\theta)$, then $\mathbf{n} \,dA = (\tfrac{\partial \mathbf{\Psi}}{\partial r} \times \tfrac{\partial \mathbf{\Psi}}{\partial \theta}) \, dr\,d\theta$ (assuming an upward orientation of $\Sigma$, which you should double-check given the orientation on the boundary).

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić How do you know that this **n** is in the right direction and that the cross-product is the right way around? My lecturer mentioned that sometimes you will consider the reverse since it can be normal in two directions.

Comment: Update: I've worked through it all and got a final answer of $0$ since the dot product in my double integral evaluated to $0$. I'm not sure if this is right or not?

Comment: The order of the cross product is based on the order of the variables in the parametrization. In this case, we have $\Psi(r, \theta),$ so the cross product will be $\Psi_r(r, \theta) \times \Psi_\theta(r, \theta).$ Now, this might not be the normal vector; that depends on how you orient the surface. But I imagine that you want to orient the surface outward, so you just need to check that this vector points in the correct direction at a point (you choose).

Comment: Either way, the normal vector is the cross product up to a sign.

Comment: For future reference, please do not use inappropriate tags.

Answer (score 1):

The Stokes theorem that you are looking for is the one using differential forms:
$$
\int_\gamma \omega = \int_S d\,\omega.
$$
Here $\gamma = \partial S$, the boundary of the surface S. (I changed your notation so that the surface is $S$ and the boundary is $\gamma$.) In this case, the surface is the portion of the parabaloid over the 1st quadrant and the boundary consists of three curves,the quarter circle $\gamma_1$ from (2,0) to (0,2) in the $xy$-plane, the portion of the parabola $\gamma_2$ in the $yz$ plane from (0,2,0) to (0,0,4), and the portion of the parabola $\gamma_3$ in the $xz$-plane back from (0,0,4) to (2,0,0). The $d$ is Cartan's exterior derivative.
$$
\begin{gathered}\omega=4x\,dx+9xy\,dy+3(x^{2}+y^{2})\,dz=4x\,dx+9xy\,dy+3(4-z)\,dz\\
d\omega=9y\,dx\wedge dy
\end{gathered}
$$
We should have
$$
\int_\gamma \omega =\int_{\gamma_1} \omega +\int_{\gamma_2} \omega+\int_{\gamma_3} \omega = \int_S d\,\omega.
$$
Let us calculate the surface integral first. The surface $S$ is parametrized by
$$
(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,4-r^{2})\qquad\begin{cases}
0\le r\le 2\\
0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}d\omega & =9y\,dx\wedge dy\\
 & =9r\sin\theta\,d(r\cos\theta)\wedge d(r\sin\theta)\\
 & =9r\sin\theta\,(\cos\theta\,dr-r\sin\theta\,d\theta)\wedge d(\sin\theta\,dr+r\cos\theta\,d\theta)\\
 & =9r\sin\theta\,r\,dr\wedge d\theta=9r^{2}\sin\theta\,dr\wedge d\theta.
\end{aligned}
$$
With this parameterization the surface integral becomes the simple double integral
$$
\int^{\pi/2}_0 \int^2_0 9r\sin\theta\,dr\,d\theta
=\left.\left.-3r^{3}\cos\theta\right|_{r=0}^{2}\right|_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}=24.
$$

Of course we should to do the line integrals to see if they agree! Let us start with the integral over $\gamma_1$. This can be parametrized by
$$
\gamma_1= (2\cos\theta,2\sin\theta,0)
$$
for $0\le \theta \le \pi/2$. Now restricting $\omega = 4x\,dx+9xy\,dy+3(4-z)\,dz$ to $\gamma_1$ gives:
$$
\left.\omega\right|_{\gamma_{1}}=
-16\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) + 72\cos^2(\theta) \sin(\theta)
$$
and
$$
\int^{\pi/2}_0 -16\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) + 72\cos^2(\theta) \sin(\theta)
\,d\theta = 16.
$$
The curves $\gamma_2$ is parameterized by $(0,2-t,4t-t^2)$ and the curve $\gamma_3$ is given be $(t,0,4-t^2)$ for $0\le t\le 2$. The reader can check that $\int_{\gamma_2} \omega = 8$ and $\int_{\gamma_2} \omega = 0$ and find that $\int_S d\omega = \int_\gamma \omega$.